# Calculating the Median Across Columns of a Table

Tags: sql, pivot, median

I need to calculate the median across column values of a table that include various age ranges, and I'm having trouble finding the answer to my problem. The table is structured as follows:

```
ID    0-5    5-10    11-15    16-20   ...
------------------------------------------
1     14     5       12       5       ...
2     5      11      14       17      ...
```

I've read about finding the median of data, using rowcount and aggregates, but that seems to require the data all be in the same column. Because of this, I think I need to use the PIVOT function within SQL, but I can't figure out the syntax needed. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you want the desired result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method that is really elegant.  I would go for brute force:

```
select id,
       (case when tot1 >= totn / 2 then 'col1'
             when tot2 >= totn / 2 then 'col2'
        . . .
       ) as mediancolumn
from (select t.*,
             col1 as Tot1,
             col1 + col2 as Tot2,
             . . .
             (col1 + col2 + . . . coln) as Totn
      from t
     ) t
```

If you actually want to parse the ranges, then the same idea holds.  But you need to change the `then` part of the `case` statement to handle the numeric values.

Comment: While Kyle's method did provide me with a great implementation of how to pivot the columns I needed, the data ended up being easier to brute force the median values out of. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want is an UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT ID, Value, AgeRange
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM ages) pivotedDate
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR AgeRAnge IN 
      ([0-5], [6-10], ...)
) AS Result;
```

Note you have to put all your age ranges in the statement to return their values.

Comment: Thank you for the great implementation of pivoting the values I needed.